# Import dynamic range from one Excel workbook to another Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I would need help with the following:

I have 3 Excel workbooks (wb1, wb2 and wb3). wb1 and wb2 both contain column A (dates) and column B (numbers). On a monthly basis, new data is added to both columns. wb1 and wb2 are stored in the same folder.

In wb3 I perform calculations based on the data of either wb1 or wb2. Therefore I need to select the respective workbook (wb1 or wb2) on a drop down list in wb3. The dynamic data range of my selection should then be copied into wb3.

Answer (score 1):

**The Set Up**

**Two workbooks saved in a folder**

[image]

**Data Validation on .xlsm workbook.**

[image]

Close .xlsx workbooks, before running the code. The code will open and close the workbook selected.

**Select Workbook and click the button**

[image]

```
    Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lstRw As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim GetRng As String
    Dim MyDir As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    GetRng = ws.Range("A2")

    MyDir = "C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\SampleFolder\"    'change folder location"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & GetRng & "*.xlsx")
    ChDir MyDir

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        lstRw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lstRw, 2))
        rng.Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = 1
    MyFile = Dir()


End Sub
```